# DateTime::createFromFormat() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am trying to get output as Current date and Time as 0:0:0
Below is my code.

```
$StartDate = new \DateTime('now');
$StartDate = $StartDate->setTime(0, 0, 0);
echo \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $StartDate);
```

but I am getting error below.

> DateTime::createFromFormat() expects parameter 2 to be string, object
>   given

Comment: $StartDate is object, but it should be string like '1975-05-21 22': http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: You want to echo a formatted string. use `$StartDate->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: @Raptor: Can I see the time also in format function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get start day && end day:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$startDate = new \DateTime($date);
$endDate = new \DateTime($date);
$endDate->modify("+1 day -1 second");

echo $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
return dd($endDate);
```

Comment: how can i echo Current date and Time as 0:0:0 ?

Comment: `return dd($startDate);` , result look like: `DateTime {#144
  +"date": "2016-03-11  00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}`

Comment: I want to return string but above code is returning object.

Answer (score 0):

change your output to:

```
echo $StartDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Here's a list of all the formatting characters that can be used to customize your output [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

Comment: i want hours minutes and second also